# Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'conv2d_2/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,174,1,40], [2,2,40,16]

Tags: python

```
%store -r x_train 
%store -r x_test 
%store -r y_train 
%store -r y_test 
%store -r yy 
%store -r le
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D,  
GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn import metric
num_rows = 40
num_columns = 174
num_channels = 1
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],num_rows , num_columns, 
num_channels)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], num_rows, 
num_columns,num_channels )

num_labels = yy.shape[1]
filter_size = 2
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, 
activation='relu',input_shape=(40,174,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))
```

this is the full code. 
when i am trying to create a model of CNN i stuck with this error.

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call 
last)
~/arshin/home/arshin/envs/aiml/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, 
 node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
 1566   try:
 -> 1567     c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
  1568   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

 InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 
 from 1 for 'conv2d_1/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: 
 [?,174,1,40], [2,2,40,16].
```

code contain no error. why this happened....... is this because of the tensorflow version or something.. I tried many things but i can't correct the error. what's the problem in this code..

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems with this code. Model should be created successfully.

Comment: but i got this error.  InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'conv2d_1/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,174,1,40], [2,2,40,16].

Comment: Can you post the complete code. This part only includes network creation and I replicated and it works correctly.

Comment: i posted as an answer

Comment: It is better if you edit your question instead of posting as an answer.

Comment: i edited the question with complete code. please check.